# How to make a form for multi user in access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a time tracker for my team where each individual do so many identical task. i split the database. but problem is that each front end user can see database of other front end users. is there anyway i can restrict user to see there data entry without any code?

Answer (score 0):

*This assumes that your users are using Windows security*

Try adding a new field to your tables, and add a default value in the field properties for

```
Environ("USERNAME")
```

This should insert the windows login username for each new record. You can then filter all your queries/forms to return only matching records. You will need to apply the filter to the underlying queries of any forms to prevent users switching off the filter and seeing everything.

Comment: i tried to add Environ("USERNAME") in default value but it shows an error unknown function 'Environ'in validation expression or default value on 'table1.name'

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have Access 2007 running so we'll have to try a couple of things, first of which is to see if you are running in sandbox mode: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/environ-function-HA001228831.aspx